# SKColor doesn't work, always white

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm trying to change the backgroundColor in a Sprite Kit Scene but SKColor doesn't work.

I'm using

```
self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:52.0 green:73.0 blue:94.0 alpha:1];
```

But always appears in white, if I try for example

```
self.backgroundColor = [SKColor redColor];
```

The background is red, What I'm doing wrong?

I've also tried with UIColor, but nope

Thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

The value range is from 0 to 1.0, what you want is

```
self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:52.0/255.0 green:73.0/255.0 blue:94.0/255.0 alpha:1];
```

Answer (score 2):

I always make this mistake.  Be sure to divide the values by 255.0

```
self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:52.0/255.0 green:73.0/255.0 blue:94.0/255.0 alpha:1];
```